# Exit velocity of a bullet traveling on a circular path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, velocity

After watching a [Mythbusters video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1lt7xw4AVs) about bullet deflection I wanted to calculate the exit velocity of a bullet entering a semi-circular shape, thus finally being deflected in the opposite direction it first travelled, as shown in the illustration below.

[image]

- $v_o$ … initial velocity
- $v_E$ … exit velocity
- $\mu_0$ … coefficient of friction
- $\phi$ … angle circular path ($=\pi$ for semi-circle)

Assuming that for a given velocity $v$ the normal Force acting on the bullet is 
$$ F_N=m\frac{v^2}{R} $$
thus the friction force is
$$ F_R=\mu F_N=\mu m\frac{v^2}{R} $$
Then I solved the differential equation
$$ -dv=\mu\frac{v^2}{R}dt $$

Finally I got to the result 
$$ v_E=\frac{v_0}{e^{\mu\phi}} $$

I am a little skeptic of the result, because apparently the radius of the curve doesn't even matter to the exit velocity.
I neglected the possibility of the Normal Force actually breaking the bullet, if the radius is small enough.

Can anyone confirm, that I did not make any mistakes or wants to check my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your answer here actually makes physical sense. The reason the radius could drop out of the final answer, and only the traversed angle be relevant is that a larger radii, the normal force would be smaller and so the friction would be less.

This smaller friction would be (exactly) compensated by the fact that the bullet has to traverse a longer distance along the arc, and so removing $R$ from the answer.